# Email headers getting lost when the email is forwarded

Tags: c#, outlook

I have decided to use custom headers in email

```
 message.Headers.Add("Origin", "My Company");
```

The problem is that when the email is forwarded these original headers seem to get lost, is there a way to ensure the original headers are kept during a forwarding operation.

Either this... or a more permanent way to store values in an html formatted message.

Comment: @JL: Not sure, but try making the header "X-Origin" and see what happens. What do the RFCs say about whether headers must be preserved when forwarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this happens. to get round it read the header from the orginal email then re add them to the Fwd email to persist.